# How can I define a the scope/environment of a service-worker JS in VSCode project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a JS (not TS) project and using VSCode/Typecripts `checkjs` feature to check/lint the project.

I'm unable to find a way of defining the scope of *just* the service-worker file to `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` without changing the scope of the other files from `Window`.

I've tried various combinations of sibling `.d.ts` files and `/// <reference lib="…" />` but many of them seem to operate on the project in a 'global' manner, changing the default-lib/scope of all `.js` files causing loads of errors.

Related Issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14877

I've created a reduced-test-case here:

https://github.com/wilsonpage/vscode-scope-test-case

Comment: wasn't the scope of the serviceworker based on it's location it was loaded from (it's been a while since I touched on that topic). Can you copy your resolution request from github to the question? On a sidenote, wouldn't you have more luck creating a new issue in the typescript repository and referencing the related issue than just piggybacking on it?

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question wasn't clear, I am referring to the environment/scope of the file in the eyes of typescript, not he runtime scope of the service-worker.